# Pandas: fillna() method with multiindex - NaNs are filled with wrong columns

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, dataframe, multi-index

Here is a working example that reproduces my problem. First some random data is generated along with the data that we will use to fill the nans:

```
#Generate some random data and data that will be used to fill the nans
data = np.random.random((100,6))
fill_data = np.vstack((np.ones(200), np.ones(200)*2, np.ones(200)*3,np.ones(200), np.ones(200)*2, np.ones(200)*3)).T

#Generate indices of nans that we will put in
nan_rows = np.random.randint(0,100,50)
nan_cols = np.random.randint(0,6,50)
nan_idx = np.vstack((nan_rows,nan_cols)).T

#Put in nan values
for r,c in nan_idx:
    data[r,c] = np.nan

#Generate multiindex and datetimeindex for both the data and fill_data
multi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B'],['one','two','three']])
idx1 = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='1990-01-01', periods=100, freq='d')
idx2 = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='1989-12-01', periods=200, freq='d')

#Construct dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, idx1, multi)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(fill_data, idx2, multi)

#fill nans from df1 with df2
df1 = df1.fillna(df2, axis=1)
```

Here is what the resulting frames look like:

```
In [167]:

df1.head()

Out[167]:
            A                                   B
            one         two         three       one         two         three
1990-01-01  1.000000    0.341803    0.694128    0.382164    0.326956    0.506616
1990-01-02  0.439024    0.552746    0.538489    0.003906    0.968498    0.816289
1990-01-03  0.200252    0.838014    0.805633    0.008980    0.269189    0.016243
1990-01-04  0.735120    0.384871    0.579268    0.561657    0.630314    0.361932
1990-01-05  0.938185    0.335212    0.678310    2.000000    0.819046    0.482535



In [168]:

df2.head()

Out[168]:
    A   B
    one     two     three   one     two     three
1989-12-01  1   2   3   1   2   3
1989-12-02  1   2   3   1   2   3
1989-12-03  1   2   3   1   2   3
1989-12-04  1   2   3   1   2   3
1989-12-05  1   2   3   1   2   3
```

**So the key here is that the dataframes are different lengths but have common labels in that the multiindexed columns are the same and the timestamp labels in df1 are within df2.**

Here is the result:

```
In [165]:

df1

Out[165]:
            A                                   B
            one         two         three       one         two         three
1990-01-01  1.000000    0.341803    0.694128    0.382164    0.326956    0.506616
1990-01-02  0.439024    0.552746    0.538489    0.003906    0.968498    0.816289
1990-01-03  0.200252    0.838014    0.805633    0.008980    0.269189    0.016243
1990-01-04  0.735120    0.384871    0.579268    0.561657    0.630314    0.361932
1990-01-05  0.938185    0.335212    0.678310    2.000000    0.819046    0.482535
1990-01-06  0.609736    0.164815    0.295003    0.784388    3.000000    3.000000
1990-01-07  1.000000    0.394105    0.430608    0.782029    0.327485    0.855130
1990-01-08  0.573780    0.525845    0.147302    0.091022    3.000000    3.000000
1990-01-09  0.591646    0.651251    0.649255    0.205926    3.000000    0.606428
1990-01-10  0.988085    0.524769    0.481834    0.486241    0.629223    0.575843
1990-01-11  1.000000    0.586813    0.592252    0.309429    0.877121    0.547193
1990-01-12  0.853000    0.097981    0.970053    0.519838    0.828266    0.618965
1990-01-13  0.579778    0.805140    0.050559    0.432795    0.036241    0.081218
1990-01-14  0.055462    1.000000    0.159151    0.538137    3.000000    0.296754
1990-01-15  0.848238    0.697454    0.519403    0.232734    0.612487    0.891230
1990-01-16  0.808238    0.182904    0.480846    0.052806    0.900373    0.860274
1990-01-17  0.890997    0.346767    0.265168    0.486746    0.983999    0.104035
1990-01-18  0.673155    0.248853    0.245246    2.000000    0.965884    0.295021
1990-01-19  0.074864    0.714846    2.000000    0.046031    0.105930    0.641538
1990-01-20  1.000000    0.486893    0.464024    0.499484    0.794107    0.868002
```

If you look closely you can see that there are values equal to 1 in columns ('A','one') and ('A','two'), values equal to 2 in ('A','three') and ('B','one') and values equal to 3 in ('B','two') and ('B','three').

The expected output would be values of 1 in the 'one' columns, 2 in the 'two' columns, etc.

Am I doing something wrong here? To me this seems like some kind of bug.

Comment: hmm, why don't you open an issue on github for this.

Comment: I agree this behavior is surprising and seems like a bug.  I can reproduce it with a much simpler example, not using DateTimeIndex or MultiIndex.  @Jeff: can you point me towards the documentation that explains exactly what `df1.fillna(df2)` is supposed to do?

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html?highlight=fillna#pandas.DataFrame.fillna. Technically this is not implemented :). Its actually quite complicated because you need to align the blocks (dtypes) of the 2 frames; certainly not tested. Let's open an issue. Maybe in the short-term raise NotImplementedError. (Pls do a pull-request if you would)

Comment: @Jeff: That documentation doesn't at all explain how fillna is supposed to work with a DataFrame argument.  Are you saying `df1.fillna(df2)` is not supported?  If so, why doesn't it raise an error?

Comment: @BrenBarn that's exactly what I am saying! I don't think it should work at all (its not documented and falls thru to an incorrect branch I think). It SHOULD raise ATM.

Comment: @Jeff I agree that this should raise for now. I wasn't sure if I was using this method wrong but an obvious workaround would be to iterate through each column and apply fillna() with axis=0. Would it be so hard to incorporate this for when the method is applied to dataframes?

Comment: As a workaround you could use `df1.where(pd.notnull(df1), df2)`.

Comment: @unutbu Nice, that is about 200x faster than my for-loop applying fillna() Series-by-Series, and it also works for data with additional column labels. I think something like this should be implemented for the fillna() method on DataFrames. You should put as answer

Comment: yeh I think using .where is the answer (or combine_first / update) which are not vectorized for this case . @unutubu can u post an issue with that suggestion pls

Comment: Issue is here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8377

Comment: @Jeff: Sorry, I didn't see your message... oh I see why: s/unutubu/unutbu... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [issue has been fixed](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/8388) in the latest version of Pandas.

Using version 0.15.0 you will be able to do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan    

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [nan, 1, 2, nan, nan],
                   'b': [1, 2, 3, nan, nan],
                   'c': [nan, 1, 2, 3, 4]},
                  index = list('VWXYZ'))
#     a   b   c
# V NaN   1 NaN
# W   1   2   1
# X   2   3   2
# Y NaN NaN   3
# Z NaN NaN   4

# df2 may have different index and columns
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
                    'b': [50, 60, 70, 80, 90],
                    'c': list('ABCDE')},
                   index = list('VWXYZ'))
#     a   b  c
# V  10  50  A
# W  20  60  B
# X  30  70  C
# Y  40  80  D
# Z  50  90  E
```

Now, passing a DataFrame to `fillna`

```
result = df.fillna(df2)
```

yields

```
print(result)
#     a   b  c
# V  10   1  A
# W   1   2  1
# X   2   3  2
# Y  40  80  3
# Z  50  90  4
```